# Dynamic variable assignment using eval in Matlab R2013a

Tags: matlab, variables, dynamic, eval, assign

I am trying to assign values to a dynamic variable using `eval` in Matlab. I'm using Matlab R2013a. I can easily do it older versions but not in R2013a. Yes, I'm aware of the pitfalls of using `eval`, etc. I tried `assignin` as well, but that wasn't successful.

```
Bins = [10 100 20]; 
Cols = numel(Bins);

for i = 1:Cols 
    eval(['Var' num2str(i) ' = Cols+i']);
end
```

Error --> Attempt to add "Var" to a static workspace.

*Desired Output*

```
    Var1 = 4 
    Var2 = 5
    Var3 = 6
```

Comment: OK, you're aware of the pitfalls of using `eval`.  So why would you not write this as an array instead? `Var(i) = Cols+i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that code inside of a nested function? See [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variables-in-nested-and-anonymous-functions.html) from The MathWorks.

If you must create variables that way (there are much better options) then you'll need to do it within the main function or use a sub-function. See this [article on sharing data between workspaces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html) for details on the different types of functions and how to use them.

Comment: No. It is not inside a nested function.

Comment: @Maddy: Well, as per the first URL, are you using an anonymous function or a function that contains a nested function to evaluate the code? Or possibly a `classdef` file? How are you calling the code?

Comment: -> I'm using it inside a function.  Yes, this function has another nested function many lines after the line where this eval code has been placed.  You are right.  I can now say why this happened.  I'll figure out a workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: @Maddy: Yep that sounds like "a function that contains a nested function". The nested function doesn't need to call the dynamic assignment code itself. If you can convert that nested function to a sub-function (remove the `end`s), then it'll likely work.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be able to do it.  Nested function is used via a function handle that is used in an `accumarray` statement, which further modifies a local variable.  I have a workaround.  Very interesting exception caused by nested function!